# How to activate team-ranked ward-skin

Tags: league-of-legends

In my stats I can see that I have "unlocked a ward-skin". I want to activate this skin, but I don't know where or how to do so. I asked some friends and they said I have to go to the shop, but I can't find this skin there.

Comment: It is in the shop, there's a ward section where you can buy and chose the ward skin.

Comment: I know but i cant find the skin there is it possible that they have a bug or someting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You havent technically unlocked the ward skin yet.**
The skin you have "Unlocked" will be rewarded with the end of season 5. You'll find all the other ward skins the following way:

In the Client shop you'll find a tab on the left side that's labeled "Ward Skins". If you click on it you should see a graphical display of all the ward skins. There's also a filter function to display the different kind of skins (Teamranked rewards are under "Limited availability"). To switch back to the default skin you can click on the "Use default wards" icon in the top right corner.

Comment: ok thank you i just tough that the ward skins are unlocked immediately because they wrote 'unlocked' under the skin

Answer (score 1):

In the shop, on the left side, you'll see a `Ward Skins` option, click on it and from there, you'll see your owned skin with a checkbox on the upper left corner which you check to select your desired skin.

Search for `Ward skins` on this [solomid page](http://www.solomid.net/guide/view/119909-generic-build-guide-by-slater-von-j-ger) to see this : [image]